# Cordova Android navigator.app.backHistory() Not Working

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova app that has a conditional statement when the Android back button is pressed. If we are on the root page I want it to do navigator.app.backHistory(), and when it's not on the root page I want it to run my own custom code. I've done it like so:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
        if(screenList.length <= 0) {
            alert("fired");
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        } else {
            //My custom code
        }
    }
}
```

My custom code runs as it should, and the alert fires when it should too, but navigator.app.backHistory() does nothing. Did this change recently? I'm using Cordova version 7.0.1